# Connection Reset error with Google Drive APIs

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, service-accounts, google-api-java-client

I am using a Google Service account to create Google Drive resources.

However when i try to execute Drive create folder API i get connection reset error.

I can confirm that the credentials for the service account are properly configured and loaded in my program.

Below is the code and the stacktrace

```
 public static File createFolder(Drive driveService) {
    File fileMetadata = new File();
    fileMetadata.setName("Testing");
    fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");

    File file =null;
    try {
        file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata)
            .setFields("id")
            .execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Exception here in create folder");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Folder ID: " + file.getId());
    
    return file;
}
```

Below is how the credentials are read and instance of Drive is created

```
/**
 * Creates credentials for the service account
 * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 */
private static Credential getServiceAccountCredential(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
     InputStream in = DriveQuickStart.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
     if (in == null) {
         throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
     }
     GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(in)
             .createScoped(SCOPES);
     System.out.println("loaded credential " + credential.getServiceAccountId()) ;
     return credential;
}

public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    SCOPES.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE);
    Drive service = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getServiceAccountCredential(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
    //create folder
    
   File parentFolder =  createFolder(service);
```

Stacktrace

```
    Exception here in create folder
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:369)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:312)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:307)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:144)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1488)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1394)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:441)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:412)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:183)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1375)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1350)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:220)
        at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
        at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:283)
        at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:394)
        at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
        at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:868)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
        at DriveQuickStart.createFolder(DriveQuickStart.java:138)
        at DriveQuickStart.main(DriveQuickStart.java:103)
        Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
                at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implWrite(NioSocketImpl.java:420)
                at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.write(NioSocketImpl.java:440)
                at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$2.write(NioSocketImpl.java:826)
                at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketOutputStream.write(Socket.java:1051)
                at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.encodeAlert(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:82)
                at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:400)
                ... 25 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:323)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:981)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:160)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:110)
        ... 22 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.google.api.services.drive.model.File.getId()" because "file" is null
        at DriveQuickStart.createFolder(DriveQuickStart.java:144)
        at DriveQuickStart.main(DriveQuickStart.java:103)
```

Comment: please edit your question and show how driveService was created

Comment: Updated with code how the instance of Drive Class is created...code is inspired from Java Google Drive Quick Start https://github.com/googleworkspace/java-samples/blob/master/drive/quickstart/src/main/java/DriveQuickstart.java

Comment: try changing it to DriveScopes.DRIVE

Comment: This worked...thanks a ton...my code was working sometime back...did the scopes changed recently ?

Comment: That's hard to tell but it might be worth posting a bug report.  If your sure this is something that used to work https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191650%2B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using `DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE` this scope can act a bit strange sometimes.  Its basicly used to lock an application and only allow it to edit files that it created itself.  When creating folders I have found it can act very strangely if the directory its creating is not inside a directory it created in the first place.

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive  See, edit, create, and delete all of your Google Drive files

The solution is to just use. `DriveScopes.DRIVE`  technically you are using a service account anyway there is really no reason to limit it.

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file    View and manage Google Drive files and folders that you have opened or created with this app

Comment: Another question...how to do proper exception handling here ?...it seems the Google java APIs are not returning the appropriate message in the exception...connection reset error for scopes missing is highly misleading...

Comment: @saurav i have been trying to tell google for around ten years that their error messages are not helpful.  They are not listening.

Comment: @DalmTo my code still stops working after some time with the same error mentioned in the original post..is it because of the access token expiry ?

Comment: Now sometime back it has started working again...i checked that if there is any quota/limit issue of the APIs but it doesn't seem to be